# What should I do if I accidentally interrupted a firmware update for my USB Internet dongle?

Tags: updates, firmware, dongle

I use a USB Internet dongle, Huawei E3372h-153. Each time I insert it in a USB port, an Opera tab opens and shows the connection status. Yesterday that tab additionally displayed a message saying that an update had to be installed. I didn't carefully read the message and do not remember the exact wording, but it was clear that the update was related to the dongle. In particular, the message said that the update might improve the performance of the dongle. So I chose the option to initiate the update and saw a warning not to close the browser during the update process. The update process was very slow, and it took a few minutes for the progress to reach 20% or so. So I got bored and started doing something else on my computer. And within a minute of getting busy with that, I accidentally closed Opera: I wanted to close another window, but misclicked and accidentally closed Opera. Opera didn't ask me whether I really wanted to close it, because only one tab was open, so Opera instantly got closed after I accidentally clicked on the close button. After this, I couldn't see any signs of the update process. I opened Opera again, but all I saw was the usual tab with the connection status. So I guess I interrupted the update process. Based on how long it took to reach 20%, I guess it would have taken about 20 minutes for the update to complete if I had not interrupted it.

In an attempt to start the update over, I clicked on "Update" in the dongle status tab in Opera. There I was offered to download a zip file. I downloaded it (MobileBrServ.zip, 2.55 Mb), unpacked it, and ran the exe file. The update took just a few seconds or so, so it was obvious it wasn't the same update I had interrupted.

Now, if I click on "Update" in the dongle status tab in Opera, I see this:

> **Current version**
>
> Software version: 22.333.63.00.778
>
> Web UI version: 17.100.21.00.778
>
> Check for updates

When I click on "Check for updates" there, I see the following message: "This version is up-to-date."

I guess that what I interrupted was a firmware update and that the zip file I downloaded did something different - a user interface update or something else.

The dongle seems to work as fine as before. I measured the ping, the download speed, and the upload speed, and they turned out to be about the same as I measured a month ago (~50 ms, ~40 Mbps, and ~20 MBps, respectively).

Should I be concerned? I'm somewhat afraid that because of the interrupted firmware update, the firmware on my dongle got corrupted, which might cause issues in the future. I tried to find firmware updates for my dongle on the manufacturer's website, but couldn't find any. What should I do?

Comment: It's difficult to say without certain, however, most firmware updates upload the payload to the device then apply it.  If the device works, then you should be good, but you can always reach out to Huawei for assistance.